# Add comments to wordpress inspect element page

Tags: wordpress, indexing, signature

As the title says, I want to add some sort of signature with comments on my wordpress index file, thing is - there are 30 different index files and none of them seems to work

Comment: What do you mean signature? Like a comment saying you made the site?

Comment: yes, i want to put comment to say that i've made the site

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it'll just be a case of adding some HTML comments (*not PHP comments as they won't show in the source code*) in your theme files. Bear in mind that editing a theme won't work if someone else made it and releases updates to it as it'll overwrite your changes if you update it.

The best place to add in the comments is to either open the `header.php` file and place your HTML comments after the opening `<body>` tag. If your theme doesn't include a header file, you could always add your comments to the top of your themes `index.php` file instead.

Your theme should be located within `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/`.

Alternatively, you could also place HTML comments between the `<head>` tags of your theme so they show up a bit higher in the source code. To do this, it's probably best to use an action hook instead. Place this in your themes `functions.php` file:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_signature_to_theme', 1, 0 );

function add_signature_to_theme() {

    ?><!-- Welcome to my website. --><?php

}
```

The [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) action hook documentation is useful to have as reference as well if you'd like a bit more information on what it is and what it does.